# Input String is not in Correct Format / DataTable.Select Method

Tags: vb.net, datatable.select

Hi I have a problem, when I am trying to use DataTable.Select to get column values..  Actually it is working file in C# which I have converted using Converters.

I am using .NET 1.1 / VS 2003...input string was not in correct format..

```
Dim drs As DataRow() = dtResults.[Select]("ISSD" + i + " =" + issd + " AND BiPad=" + bipad)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing a little because I don't know what dataType bipad is (and I haven't done VB.NET in about 6 years...)

```
Dim drs As DataRow() = dtResults.Select("ISSD" & i.ToString() & " = '" & issd.ToString() & "' AND BiPad = '" & bipad.ToString() & "'")
```